# saving an ArrayList<String> state in a SQLiteDatabase (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm working on a android app that will display Strings to the user, and the user then has the option to add one to a favorite list. I have searched and searched and cannot find the proper way of doing this. I did get one open source project, everything worked until the user removed a favorite. The database would clear the row of data, but when a new row is added, it would behave as if the deleted row still had data, leaving blanks in the favorite list.

this is my insert method

```
  public long insertString(String newString) 
  {
    ContentValues newStringValue = new ContentValues();

    newStringValue.put(KEY_STRING, newString);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, newStringValue);
  }
```

the long returned will always increment even if i use the remove method:

```
 public boolean removeString(long _rowIndex)
  {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + _rowIndex, null) > 0;
  }
```

if i try to remove the third index, and the user removed a question at the third index, the method returns false, is there a way to completely remove all rows with no data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) or [ResourceCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ResourceCursorAdapter.html) and when you modify the data call [cursor.requery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery()) to refresh everything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just encode String List as something like JSON, then save as long string (blob / clob)? I would use [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org), but there are many alternatives to choose from (Guice, or XStream if you prefer XML). I mean, assuming you don't really need relational aspects of data (no need to find users with specific list entry by querying) but just need to persist lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class OrderManager

{

private MyDBOpenHelper _db_Orders;

private static final String GET_Orders = “SELECT * FROM “+Order_TABLE_NAME ;


public OrderManager(Context context)

{

_db_Orders = new MyDBOpenHelper(context);

}


public boolean insert(String orderName, String orderStatus)

{

try

{

SQLiteDatabase sqlite = _db_Orders.getWritableDatabase();

/*

sqlite.execSQL(“INSERT INTO “+ Order_TABLE_NAME +

” (” + KEY_NAME +”, “+ KEY_STATUS + “)” +

” VALUES (‘” + orderName + “‘, ‘” + orderStatus + “‘)”);

*/


ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, orderName);

initialValues.put(KEY_STATUS, orderStatus);

sqlite.insert(Order_TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);


}

catch(SQLException sqlerror)

{

Log.v(“Insert ERROR”, sqlerror.getMessage());

return false;

}


return true;

}


public ArrayList<Order> getOrders()

{

ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();


SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = _db_Orders.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor crsr = sqliteDB.rawQuery(GET_Orders, null);


Log.v(“Select Query result”, String.valueOf(crsr.getCount()) );


crsr.moveToFirst();

for(int i=0; i < crsr.getCount(); i++)

{

orders.add(new Order(crsr.getString(0), crsr.getString(1)));

//Log.v(“DATA”, crsr.getString(0) + ” ” +crsr.getString(1));

crsr.moveToNext();

}


return orders;

}

}
```